# I cannot dynamically hide UI Bootstrap's popover directive in a custom directive [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a custom AngularJS directive that will enable users to select a range of text and add a comment/annotation to that selection of text, similar to [Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/).

In my directive's `link` function, there are two event handlers. The first (below) fires when the user clicks on the custom directive. I am using UI Bootstrap's [Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover) directive and adding it to my span element to display a popover.

```
element.on('click', function () {
    if (!isPopoverActive) {
        selectedRangeId = generateRandomString(10);

        // wrap the selected range in a span element and 
        // give it a generated random ID
        highlightElement(selectedRangeId);

        if (elementExists(selectedRangeId)) {
            highlightedElement = getElementById(selectedRangeId);

            // Add UI Bootstrap's popover directive attributes to the element
            highlightedElement.attr('uib-popover-template', "'directives/my.directive/my.directive.tpl.html'");
            highlightedElement.attr('popover-is-open', true);
            highlightedElement.attr('popover-placement', 'right');
            highlightedElement.attr('popover-trigger', 'manual');
            highlightedElement.attr('popover-title', 'Comment');

            $compile(highlightedElement)(scope);

            isPopoverActive = true;
        }
    }
});
```

The second (below) fires on a `mouseup` event anywhere on the current page. If the clicked element is outside of the popover I want to hide the popover again but this does not work. Inspecting the element in my browser finds that the `popover-is-open` attribute value changes on the `span` but nothing is happening on the page.

```
$document.on('mouseup', function (event) {
    var clickedElement = event.toElement;

    if (isPopoverActive && clickedElement.id !== selectedRangeId && !isDescendant('popover', clickedElement.id)) {
        highlightedElement.attr('popover-is-open', false);
        $compile(highlightedElement)(scope);
    }
});
```

Comment: Create a plunk which reproduces the problem and you will get answers faster. Give that a try.